# Changing indexes of sum with lg

Tags: summation, logarithms

I've seen the following equation (in [CLRS Instructor’s Manual](http://www.r-5.org/files/books/computers/algo-list/common/Cormen_Lin_Lee-Introduction_to_Algorithms_(Solutions)-EN.pdf), page 4-12):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\lg{n}-1}\frac{n}{\lg{n}-i} = n\sum_{i=1}^{\lg{n}}\frac{n}{i}= n\sum_{i=1}^{\lg{n}}\frac{1}{i}
$$

I can't seem to understand these transitions.
The $n$ was brought out of the sum, thus we can get
 $$ = n\sum_{i=0}^{\lg{n}-1}\frac{1}{\lg{n}-i}$$

I see the summation index change, but I don't understand how it turns $\lg{n}-i$ to $i$

Furthermore, the last transition seems like a mistake. Shouldn't it be
$$ = n^2 \sum_{i=1}^{\lg{n}}\frac{1}{i} $$
?

If that's mistake, maybe the first one is also a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \frac{n}{t-i} = \frac{n}{t} + \frac{n}{t-1} + \cdots + \frac{n}{1}  = \sum_{x=1}^{t} \frac{n}{x} = n \sum_{x=1}^{t} \frac{1}{x}.$$
In your problem, $t = \lg(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that
$n$ is a power of $2$,
$n = 2^m$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=0}^{\lg{n}-1}\frac{1}{\lg{n}-i}
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{m-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{m-(m-i)}
\qquad\text{replace } i \text{ by } m-i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{i}\\
\end{array}
$